# Adding elements stops for a while in huge ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

While I was debugging performance of program with huge calculating task I have discovered that most of time of adding elements to big ArrayList is being taken  by adding 1 element. Can anyone explain why such thing happens?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainArr {
    ArrayList<Integer> normalList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainArr m = new MainArr();
        m.addElements();
    }

    public void addElements() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int j = 0; j < 20000000; j++) {
            long addTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.normalList.add(j);
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - addTime > 50) {
                System.out.println("slow index-" + j + " - time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - addTime));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End after:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }
}
```

Output(always the same indexes and times):

```
slow index-4102267 - time:1184
slow index-6758091 - time:1444
slow index-12459620 - time:3124
slow index-14738741 - time:166
End after:6651
```

Comment: As in code you see - everytime I have stop moment in the same indexes. Time differences are at most 150ms. The longest pause is always with index 12459620 .

Comment: No idea but did you try if things change if you use the other constructor `new ArrayList(20000000)` or the ArrayList's method public void `ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)`? Or may be if you change the amount of memory assigned to your JVM (although I don't think it has something to do with GC as it probably wouldn't be so precisely repeatable).

Comment: how many records did u find  at the end?

Comment: @Salman he posted his code. Have a look at it.

Comment: i know the code, but it doesn't say anythinh how many times it gets printed

Comment: @Salman Whole written above output is printed every execution and nothing more.

Comment: If you want to do microbenchmarks like this, best is to use JMH: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: If any of the provided solution worked, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.

So, under the hood, an `ArrayList` is a fixed-size array that gets copied over and replaced when it gets full.  So what's happening at your `slow index` marks is `ArrayList` is having to reallocate a new internal array and copy the old array into the new one.

If you want a speedup, and you know roughly how big the `ArrayList` is going to be (like in your example), use the [`ArrayList` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) that lets you specify an initial array size.

```
ArrayList<Integer> normalList = new ArrayList<>(20000000);
```

#### Edit - New Answer:

With the above answer I was getting the same performance as @MichalLis, so I did some research, and I found a different answer.

If you take the example code and replace the `ArrayList` with a plain old `int[]` array, the program spits out:

```
End after:2263
```

Then I replaced the `int[]` array with an `Integer[]` array, and got this:

```
slow index-4022087 - time:2012
slow index-8150728 - time:948
slow index-14442110 - time:4886
End after:10309
```

It turns out, since an `ArrayList` actually cannot use `int`s and must use `Integer`s, there are performance impacts from creating the new objects.  `int`s are far faster than `Integer`s, since the former is a primative type while the latter is a wrapper object.

If you want the performance benefits of an `int[]` with the resizing ability of an `ArrayList`, you can always implement your own `ArrayList` class specifically for `int`s.

```
public class IntArrayList {

    int[] array = new int[10];
    int size = 0;

    public int get(int index){
        return array[index];
    }

    public void add(int value){
        if(size == array.length){
            resizeArray();
        }
        array[size] = value;
        size++;
    }

    private void resizeArray(){
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length * 2];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            newArray[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = newArray;
    }

    public void set(int index, int value){
        array[index] = value;
    }

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

    public void remove(int index){
        for(int i=index; i<size-2; i++){
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
        size--;
    }
}
```

This is not a very robust implementation, but it is a starting point.

Output of OP's code using above `IntArrayList` implementation:

```
End after:2315
```

Comment: here are some comparisons
Without size constructor:
End after:11894

With size constructor:
End after:7143

Comment: Surprisingly my results with this constructor are slower.
End after:8974 Without parameter - End after:6651

Comment: Did you try multiple measurements to rule out GC and other aspects?

Comment: And if you want to play, you can try to call the ArrayList's `public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)` method shortly before the slow elements  in your original program, measure how long it takes and compare it to your original results.

Comment: Added at the start of loop following code:
`if(j==4102267){
    this.normalList.ensureCapacity(1000);
   }`
It does not change the results

Comment: who says array relocate? do u have a reference for it?

Comment: Thanks, in terms of writing program - it solves the problem. Still I wonder about 1 thing - I have edited starting post to display it.

Comment: @MichałLis I'm not sure that the `ArrayList`'s capacity is the primary issue; see my edit

Comment: If we consider performance - yes now I understand that ArrayList is not the best structure to use. However I have a poser about strange behaviour of capacity increasing - I added it in edit.

Comment: @MichałLis your edit about capacity increasing should be asked as a separate question

Comment: Ok. [Separate topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121048/arraylist-capacity-size-increasing-strange-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this happens due to the fact that an ArrayList grows from time to time to accommodate more elements. For example: If intial size of array inside the array list was 8, then on adding 9th element new array of increased size will be created and old array will be copied to it. This step starts consuming time when then number of elements become too large.
To prevent this, you should use LinkedList<> instead of ArrayList<>.

```
List<Integer> myHugeList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

But if your code requires ArrayList<> due to requirement of index lookups then you should initialize your ArrayList by providing expected final size of your list.

```
List<Integer> myHugeList = new ArrayList<Integer>(expectedSizeInInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to see what kind of tasks you do more. If you are mostly modifing the list then you should go with **LinkedList** that doesn't do resizing like **ArrayList**. If you are doing **random access** operations indexOf(..), get(index) etc. then you should go with ArrayList.

You can also **tweak** ArrayList by giving an initial size.

Btw, there seems to be a **third party library** called **Brownies Collections** that gives the most of the both worlds in a single implementation called **GapList**.

> http://www.magicwerk.org/page-collections-overview.html
>
> GapList combines the strengths of both ArrayList and LinkedList. It is
>   implemented to offer both efficient random access to elements by index
>   (as ArrayList does) and at the same time efficient adding and removing
>   elements to and from beginning and end (as LinkedList does). It also
>   exploits the locality of reference often seen in applications to
>   further improve performance, e.g. for iterating over the list....